# Force Google Script to use same IP for request from UrlFetchApp fetch

Tags: google-apps-script, request, fetch, urlfetch

I am playing with Google Script UrlFetchApp fetch and figured out, that the requests it makes are done from different IP addresses. If you call UrlFetchApp.fetch() multiple times, every request is made from another IP.

I am using DigestAuth and a SessionId to make my requests and I am getting 403 Forbidden because the call to get the SessionId (which is IP-based) is from a different IP.

f.e.
Call to get the SessionId was from 107.178.192.**52**
and the call which uses the IP-based SessionId was from 107.178.192.**56**

Can I force UrlFetchApp.fetch() to make the requests from the same IP?

Comment: Could you share a method of figuring out the IP address of UrlFetchApp request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible unfortunately.

The ranges of IPS used by google apps scripts however are available:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc

Check the section "Setup for other databases" on that page.

Comment: I have no access to the server-side, there is no way to enter any whitelisting or anything. The only way would be to force google script to use the same IP for all requests. Thats sad :(

Comment: This is indeed unfortunate.